# Комбинированный запрос Linq2SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq, uwp, linq2sql

Проект C# UWP Windows 10

Есть две таблицы SQLite.

При выборке из главной таблицы нужно заполнить недостающие данные из дочерней таблицы (эти поля в классе основной таблицы помечены атрибутом `[Ignore]`).

Код примера:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(SQLITE_PLATFORM, DB_PATH))
{
    var res = db.Table<Table1>().Where(i => i.TimeStamp >= Stamp).Select(i =>
    {
        i.Param1 = db.Get<Table2>(i.table2ref).Title;
        i.Param2 = db.Get<Table2>(i.table2ref).Type;
        i.Param3 = db.Get<Table2>(i.table2ref).Symbol;
        return i;
    });
    return res.ToList();
}
```

Проблема в том что оператор `.select` (судя по производительности запроса) заполняет не только значения результата `.Where` , а записи всей базы (в некоторых случаях по ним тоже нужно делать выборку). При том что в базе находится 10К+ записей, производительность мягко говоря так себе...

Сейчас у меня в главной таблице все необходимые поля заполняются при `Insert`е, это дает мне возможность очень быстро делать выборки, но если одна из записей в дочерней таблице изменится (что бывает очень часто), мне необходимо изменять все связанные с ней поля в главной таблице и перегружать интерфейс, что так же очень долго.

Собственно вопрос в том, как делать подобные выборки без нагрузки на базу? Подскажите решение данной проблемы...

Comment: Как вы считали производительность?

Comment: @PavelMayorov На глаз. ))

Answer (score 1):

Единственный способ выполнить ваш запрос без индекса по полю TimeStamp - это перебрать все записи в таблице. Разумеется, это будет работать долго, и Select тут ни при чем - без него все будет работать так же долго.

Сделайте индекс по полю TimeStamp и будет вам щастье.

Comment: Сделал индекс по полю `TimeStamp `, само собой выборка происходит быстро, но в `select` заполняются недостающие поля (их примерно 10, из 3х разных таблиц по индексам), записей в основной таблице очень много, а отсюда и проседание времени загрузки. Как поступать в таком случае? Можно ли как то вместо `Get` использовать `join`, что бы с него необходимые поля заполнить значениями? Особенно если фильтр по `TimeStamp` захватывает несколько тысяч записей

Comment: @SYL нет смысла - JOIN по сути будет использовать все те же самые геты. База данных-то локальная, поэтому количество запросов к ней не играет роли, важно лишь количество чтений с диска.

Comment: @SYL сокращайте число запросов, кэшируйте уже загруженные записи и т.п.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FqXnbnuE - вот пример фильтрованного запроса. В зависимости от пользовательских настроек может возвращать от нескольких записей до 10К записей. В данном случае чем больше записей попадает под фильтр - тем дольше грузиться. Причем время загрузки увеличивается не пропорционально

Comment: Ну просто напрашивается локальный кэш аккаунтов, мерчантов, инструментов и особенно тэгов!

Comment: Ну они ведь локально в SQLite и хранятся

Comment: напрашивается локальный кэш *в памяти*, который создается на 1 запрос

Comment: Я об этом думал, но разве нельзя организовать запрос так что бы не делать дополнительных? Я просто пытаюсь это сделать через Linq, через SQL куда проще такое реализовать

Comment: Можно. Пишите запрос самостоятельно, на чистом SQL. Или перейдите на ORM какую-нибудь.

Answer (score 0):

Вы делаете на каждую строку три вызова `db.Get<Table2>(i.table2ref)`. Linq2SQLite - довольно простая обертка над БД, и кешированием результатов она не занимается.

Если делать вызов 1 раз на строку - вы получите ускорение в 3 раза.

Кроме того, проверьте тип данных, используемый для первичного ключа. Если в качестве первичного ключа используется System.Int64 (long) - то выборка по первичному ключу работает еще в два раза быстрее.

Кстати, допускаются ли повторяющиеся table2ref? Если да - то кеширование результатов подзапроса в словаре может еще сильнее сократить время.

---

PS ну и глупый вопрос - а по полю `TimeStamp` у вас в БД вообще индекс есть?

Comment: table2ref - это `GUID`. Повторения могут быть конечно. По `TimeStamp` индекса нету.

Comment: Ну блин, при чем в таком случае тут вообще select?!